# Google Analytics and page tracking parameters

Tags: google-analytics

Below I've put some calls for page tracking:

1. `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])` - takes URL listed in the URL bar at the top of the browser
2. `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/sample/url'])` - takes sample URL passed as a parameter
3. `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', ''])` - takes what...? (empty string or full URL like in case 1 ?)

I'm wondering if case 3 behaves in the same way case 1 - takes the URL listed in the URL bar at the top of the browser or an empty string ?

Regards

Comment: Here is the ga.js reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will handle the `trackPageview` call as if you did not provide a custom URI.

Open your website on Chrome and use the [Google Analytics Tracking Code Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)

I tried to manually push to _gaq and it logged the following:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '']);
ga_debug.js:12_gaq.push processing : "[_trackPageview,]"
```

And a bit further down it showed me that the actual browser URI was submitted to Analytics.

Comment: You're welcome. It's so much more comfortable than e.g. HttpFox. However, I've had sites where it did not detect anything while HttpFox whould show __utm.gif requests.